# jQuery adding search (ajax, perhaps?) filter to look through spans with prefix

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, search

I'm building an icon library where the user on the front end (submitting a form) can select an icon. I managed to get everything working as far as the selection process. Now, the final product will have over 400 icons, and i wanted to add a search (ajax, i guess) or autocomplete input where the user can type a couple of letters and it filter's out those icons.

They search will be filtering out some  with a class that has the prefix "icon-".

I started on jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/yQMvh/28/

an example would be something like this :
http://anthonybush.com/projects/jquery_fast_live_filter/demo/

My HTML Markup:

```
 <div class="iconDisplay">Display's selected icon</div>
 <span id="selectedIcon" class="selected-icon" style="display:none"></span>

 <button id="selectIconButton">Select Icon</button>

 <div id="iconSelector" class="icon-list">

     <div id="iconSearch">
         <label for="icon-search">Search Icon: </label>
         <input type="text" name="icon-search" value="">
     </div>

     <span class="icon-icon1"></span>
     <span class="icon-icon2"></span>
     <span class="icon-icon3"></span>
     <span class="icon-icon4"></span>
     <span class="icon-icon5"></span>
     <span class="icon-icon6"></span>
     <span class="icon-icon7"></span>
     <span class="icon-icon8"></span>

 </div>
```

JS (note: this includes the selection jQuery as well):

```
 var iconVal = $(".icon_field").val();
 $('#selectedIcon').addClass(iconVal);

 $("#selectIconButton").click(function () {
     $("#iconSelector").fadeToggle();
 });

 $("#iconSelector span").click(function () {
     selectIcon($(this));
 });

 function selectIcon(e) {
     var selection = e.attr('class');
     $(".icon_field").val(selection);
     $("#iconSelector").hide();
     $('#selectedIcon').removeClass();
     $('#selectedIcon').addClass(selection).show();
     return;
 }
```

Comment: example: http://anthonybush.com/projects/jquery_fast_live_filter/demo/

Comment: I can't add a plugin though. I'm using wordpress as the backend of my site and it's largely complicated adding jquery plugins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will this work for you? http://jsfiddle.net/yQMvh/37/

I've modified your input field slightly (added an id)

```
<input type="text" id="txt-icon-search" name="icon-search" />
```

and added this bit of code.

```
/**
 *    Holds information about search. (document later)
 */
var search = {
    val: '',
    icons: function (e) {
        // get all the icons.
        var icons = $('span[class*="icon-"]');

        // assign the search val. (can possibly use later)
        search.val = $(e.currentTarget).val();

        // let the looping begin!
        for (var i = 0, l = icons.length; i < l; i++) {

            // get the current element, class, and icon after "icon-"
            var el = $(icons[i]),
                clazz = el.attr('class'),
                iconEnd = clazz.substr(5, clazz.length);

            // was the value found within the list of icons?
            // if found, show.
            // if not found, hide.
            (iconEnd.indexOf(search.val) === -1) ? el.hide() : el.show();
        }
    }
};

$('#txt-icon-search').keyup(search.icons);
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way could be to use DataTables, this framework includes a search functionality, its row based tho, could be modified probably. Or if you want to present each icon with some facts like size, name, creator, it would be good maybe. The user could then sort the height etc.

Have a look [here](https://datatables.net/)

Its a bit heavy weight but have a lot of possibilities for optimization

Comment: not what I'm looking for mate. something like this perhaps http://anthonybush.com/projects/jquery_fast_live_filter/demo/

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is something like this: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/
Pretty easy and all ready to use. You could pre-populate the available tags with your icons selection. Quick example:

```
$(function() {
  var availableTags = [
    "icon-name1",
    "icon-name2",
    "icon-name3",
    "etc."    
  ];
  $( "input[name=icon-search]" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
  });
});
```

EDIT: of course you can do something much more sophisticated, like displaying a thumbnail/preview of your icon next to each result

EDIT2:
From the sample in your link, I quickly threw something together to have it the way you wanted it:

JSCODE:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $.expr[':'].Contains = function(a,i,m){
      return ($(a).attr("data-index") || "").toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase())>=0;
    };

  function listFilter(header, list) {

    $("input.filterinput")
      .change( function () {
        var filter = $(this).val();
        if(filter) {
          $(list).find("span:not(:Contains(" + filter + "))").parent().slideUp();
          $(list).find("span:Contains(" + filter + ")").parent().slideDown();
        } else {
          $(list).find("li").slideDown();
        }
        return false;
      })
    .keyup( function () {
        $(this).change();
    });
  }

  $(function () {
    listFilter($("#iconSearch"), $("#list"));
  });
});
</script>
```

Your html code tweaked a little:

```
<div id="iconSelector" class="icon-list" style="display: block;">
    <div id="iconSearch">
        <label for="icon-search">Search Icon: </label>
        <input type="text" name="icon-search" class="filterinput" value="">
    </div>
    <ul id="list">
        <li><span class="icon-icon1" data-index="red"></span></li>
        <li><span class="icon-icon2" data-index="yellow"></span></li>
        <li><span class="icon-icon3" data-index="blue"></span></li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Now if you type "red" you'll get the first span since the search is looking for a match from the `data-index` attribute. You can replace those with "Facebook", "Twitter", or whatever the name of your icon is.

If you want to directly search from the class name you can do something like this then:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $.expr[':'].Contains = function(a,i,m){
      return ($(a).attr("class") || "").toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase())>=0;
  };

  function listFilter(header, list) {

    $("input.filterinput")
      .change( function () {
        var filter = "icon-" + $(this).val();
        if(filter) {
          $(list).find("span:not(:Contains(" + filter + "))").parent().slideUp();
          $(list).find("span:Contains(" + filter + ")").parent().slideDown();
        } else {
          $(list).find("li").slideDown();
        }
        return false;
      })
    .keyup( function () {
        $(this).change();
    });
  }

  $(function () {
    listFilter($("#iconSearch"), $("#list"));
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: There are over 450 icons in which I probably won't be able to type. I tried looking at autocomplete and jQueryUI, but i feel like it might the feature. Any other suggestions?

Comment: autocomplete is neat but it shows a drop down of the name of the icon. I'm looking for something like this [link](http://resource.grapii.com/files/jQueryFilter/ulExample.html)

Comment: Oh I see now. Have you tried to replicate the code used in the link you sent me? Seems like you could nest some custom attributes with your icons so the search would work just like his. By the way, what would you want to type to get a specific icon, a color?

Comment: it would be a name, like twitter, facebook, tumblr. etc, there are over 500 icons! but the <span> class all start with the prefix icon-{SEARCH NAME HERE}. i tried replicating the code but it crashes everything. I dont want to add a jQuery plugin because using wordpress and implementing  jquery plugins like that are tough to do via plugin.

Comment: It might just work, BUT, instead of data-index attribute, it needs to search by the class name. the icon name is actually in the class, prefixed with "icon-" for example: class="icon-FACEBOOK" or class="icon-HELLO"

Comment: alright you can do this with the additional edit I just made. Now looking at the `class` attribute and appending whatever is being typed to a string `icon-`